# How to set a defined distance between nodes to digitize in qgis?

Tags: qgis, distance, digitizing, vertices

Using QGIS (by now I have the 2.4 version) I would like to set some parameter (I don't know if such exists) that would impose a definite or maximal distance between nodes when digitizing a polyline or polygon.

I need this to respect a minimal grain in the mapped features which I have to bring out.

For example I would like to set a digitizing distance between nodes of -let say- 15 m, that is, when digitizing, I will be forced to make a node either all 15 meters (not more, not less) or at least all 15 m (i.e. within few to max. 15 m).

I searched in QGIS menu : Settings > Options > Digitizing, and also in plugins but could not find anything that seems appropriate to me. But maybe I overlooked something ?

Thanks a lot for any help.

NB : I don't want to calculate nor find out distances ! I want to set them.

Comment: Isn't this contradicting: "15 meters (not more, not less) or at least all 15 m (i.e. within few to max. 15 m)"?

Comment: This should happen while you digitize and post-process densify will not make you happy? That could be done with ogr2ogr by using the -segmentize option http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html. Perhaps you should try OpenJUMP and use the Draw constrained linestring tool after activating and setting the segment length steps to 15 m in the settings.

Comment: @underdark : you may see it as contradicting, but I meant it as an alternative to widen a little the potential solutions to my needs : I would like to set a parameter that allow me to respect the needed grain for the mapped features. In the first alternative (no more no less than 15 m) it would be a bit restrictive but still scope my needs if such possibility exist. I would indeed prefer the second alternative (few to max. 15m) which scopes with my need and would leave me some flexibility.

Comment: @user30184 : The second option you mention sounds like it would be what I look for, but I would by far prefer to stay by QGIS as I don't know OpenJump. For the first proposition you suggest, I don't know what is post-process densify. Is that, e.g., if I had one 48m-long segment, it would split it into three 15m-long and one 3m-long segments or something like that ? If it is so, it would "result as" but it looks like a tricky solution and using it would not be honest to scope with my need.

Comment: With post-process I meant that you could digitize the whole job ready with QGIS, save the result into shapefile and finally add more vertices by converting the result into a new shapefile with ogr2ogr by using the -segmentize switch. Your 48 m example is right and this system would not prevent digitizing less than 15 m long lines. You can try OpenJUMP and if the tool feels right for you make a feature request about implementing similar for QGIS.

Comment: @user30184 : thanks for your confirmation. I'll see what I can do with OpenJump. The post-process option would definitely be an illusion of what I would have to do : it would not better the grain (i.e. the precision of digitized features) but only add more nodes. That's not what I have to bring out. Anyway, thank you very much for these suggestions.